# How to change disabled attribute in input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change **disabled** attribute from disabled to the enabled for **input** tag using javascript in the double click.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's very possible. Get the element (by id, class, whatever), and set its `disabled` property appropriately. You can also use one of the several ways of listening for an event, specifically the double click event. What all have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ian, are you sure... ;)

Comment: I have no experience with css, I am only know winapi, but for project I am work, some of code use IE rendering engine.

Comment: @epascarello Which part are you talking about, the double click? As I look into it on the internet, I found it's not what I thought. I must be spoiled by jQuery's support for it. I could've sworn it's a common event that's always been available

Comment: @epascarello Ohhh, or are you talking about capturing click events on a disabled element?

Comment: I am not using jquery or another framework

Comment: ok, sorry my initial answer wouldn't work, check my new one, I tested it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with `.disabled`

```
document.getElementById("elementID").disabled = false;
```

Or `.removeAttr`

```
document.getElementById("elementID").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CGy6j/

Since `disabled` elements dont register click events, wrap your `input` in a `span` and do the logic on that:

```
<span id="wrapper"><input type="text" id="testInput"  /></span>

var input = document.getElementById("testInput"),
    fake = document.getElementById("wrapper");

fake.ondblclick = function() {
    input.disabled = !input.disabled;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted, but it's funny, +10 buddy

Comment: Only answers half the question, answer the other half which is the hard part.

Comment: (din't downvote) but `.removeAttr()` shouldn't be `removeAttribute()`?

Comment: oh yes, he needs to know how to capture the double click event on an input element

Comment: Thanks, pythonian29033, I have no experience with css. :-(

Comment: And the answer is not as simple as setting the dbl click event on the input.

Comment: Working up a fiddle now, couple mins

Comment: ok @user2120666 my new answer should work for you I tested it and it works

Comment: OK. Thanks. I upvote all answers, but you do hardest work, so accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Now the fun here is the fact that disabled elements do not fire mouse events, so you can not add an event listener to the element. You need to listen for the double click event up the DOM chain.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="frm">
    <input type="text" id="foo" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("frm").ondblclick = function (evt) {   //there are better ways of adding events
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;  //get what was clicked on
    if (target.disabled) {  //see if it was disabled
         target.disabled = false;   
    }
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzH28/)

Now the issue is not all browsers even propogate the event for disabled elements!

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising. Is possible using class name instead id?

Comment: Yes, you can. `document.getElementsByClassName("theClass")[0].ondblclick`

Answer (score 0):

ok, so using tymeJVs answer together with this event "ondblclick" you'll use something like this;

```
<script>
   function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById("inField").removeAttribute('disabled');
   }
</script>

<div ondblclick="myFunction();"><input id="inField" disabled=disabled/></div>
```

Comment: Won't work - disabled elements dont register click events. You need a hidden input overlayed to register